# Error trying to pass object in argument of its own method

Tags: java

I have a class "Character" that contains an ArrayList of "State" object. These state objects have a method trigger(Character charac) that needs to use the character object they are stocked in :

```
public abstract class State {
    private int turns;
    public void trigger(Character charac){
        action(charac);
        turns--;
    }
    public abstract void action(Character charac);
}
```

When i try to use "this" as argument (look in triggerStates method below), netbeans tells me "incompatible types: projet.m1s1.Character cannot be converted to java.lang.Character"

```
public class Character extends Living{

    private ArrayList states;

    public Character(String name,int life, int mana, int strengh, int intelligence, int armor){
        super(name,life,mana,strengh,intelligence,armor);
        states = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void triggerStates(){
        for(int i=0 ; i<states.size() ; i++){
            try{
                State sta = (State)states.get(i);
                sta.trigger(this);
            }
            catch (ClassCastException e){
                System.out.println("ClassCastException in Character.TriggerStates");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope i made myself clear and didn't ask a frequently asked question.

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: Don't name your class `Character`. You would have to fully qualify it every time, because `java.lang.Character` has precedence.

Comment: why dont you change your character class' name. For example MyCharacter. Because Character is a class in java.lang package.

Comment: Hahaha so dumb of me ! Thank you, not the first time i use Character as class name and i get strange errors like this

Answer (score 0):

You have imported the wrong class in your imports. You have imported `java.lang.Character` while you should be importing `projet.m1s1.Character`.

When running your code locally I get no issues this way.

Comment: Well these two classes are in separated packages, Character is in root and State is in "state" package.

Comment: In Character i imported "import projet.m1s1.state.*;" and did no import at all in State

Comment: If you don't import `projet.m1s1.Character` manually inside `State` it will default to `java.lang.Character` (hence why others suggested a different name might be better)

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to make it work, these two class were in separate packages and i just needed to import "import projet.m1s1.Character;" in State class